# Opening a specific form in another instance of Access with VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

So I looked around a lot here and couldn't find the answer to my problem. At least not completely.

Here's the case:

I am in DBase1 and want to click a button and open the form NeuSteckbrief in DBase2 in a separate instance of access.

I amanaged to open DBase2 in a separate instance with this code:

```
 Private Sub SteckbriefDB_Click()

 Dim dq As String
 Dim strExe As String
 Dim strMdb As String
 Dim strRun As String
 Dim dblReturnVal As Double

 dq = """"

 'Define var strExe; Miscosoft Access
 strExe = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE"

 'Define var strMdb; Steckbrief database location
 strMdb = "Correct Path\SteckbriefDB.accdb"

 'Define the entire statement to implement at Shell
 strRun = dq & strExe & dq & " " & dq & strMdb & dq

 'Run the code to open the project database
 dblReturnVal = Shell(strRun, vbMaximizedFocus)


End Sub
```

My problem is in opening the form NeuSteckbrief in the just opened DB. I tried to add DoCmd.OpenForm "NeuSteckbrief", acNormal but that's not working.

Do you have an idea how to adjust my code in a way that I open the DB and the correct form?

Comment: The answer to your question seems to be [further down](http://p2p.wrox.com/access-vba/50519-opening-another-instance-access-vba.html) at the site where you copied the code from, using OpenCurrentDatabase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *really* use OLE automation for something like this:

```vb
Private Sub SteckbriefDB_Click()
 Dim strMdb As String
 'Define var strMdb; Steckbrief database location
 strMdb = "Correct Path\SteckbriefDB.accdb"
 Dim appSecondInstance As New Access.Application
 With appSecondInstance
    .Visible = True
    .UserControl = True
    .OpenCurrentDatabase strMdb
    .DoCmd.OpenForm "NeuSteckbrief", acNormal
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the really fast reply and help! It works like a charm. I had not idea how to solve it, so my solution was a lot of google research and try&error.

Comment: I tried it an saw that I had to adjust it to add a new record, which I did with this ".DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "NeuSteckbrief", acNewRec"