# Addressing a specific Access Form from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have an Excel sheet with a command button, which opens an Access form and fills it with data from the sheet.

If I have two Access instances running (different databases) I get the message that VBA can not find the form.

Is it possible to address a specific database form?

Current Code: `DoCmd.OpenForm ("FORM_ABC")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opening a specific form in another instance of Access with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49629251/opening-a-specific-form-in-another-instance-of-access-with-vba)

Comment: Please post your code. No one can debug without seeing the code.

Comment: There is not really any code to post, the question is more conceptional. Is it possible or not? I have one Excel sheet, and two different access databases running. A command button in excel should open a form in on of these access databases. Excel always addresses the wrong access db. I do not want to open a second instance or something similiar

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you need a Form to do this kind of thing. Here's one way to send data from Excel to Access.

```
Sub InsertIntoX2()

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, row As Long
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
            "Data Source=C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\Test.accdb;"

    ' open a recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "tblTrx", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

    row = 3    ' the start row in the worksheet
    Do While Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row))

        With rs
            .AddNew    ' create a new record
            .Fields("ID") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row).Value
            .Fields("Product") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & row).Value
            .Fields("ProdDate") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & row).Value
            .Update
        End With
        row = row + 1
    Loop

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

If you want to use an Excel form to capture data and save the data to a Worksheet, and then send the results to Access, use the VBA code sample described above.